# how to replace the content of NSMutablestring in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I am new in objective c. I want to replace the content of mutable string I am using code as

```
NSMutableString *myMutableStringObj = [myMutableStringObj stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" & " withString:@"And"];
```

But It Shows me warning 
Incomparable pointer types assigning to `NSMutableString *` from `NSString *`

Any Suggestion about this. I am using `MutableString`.

Comment: buz stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString returns NSString not  NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you this function returns `NSString *`. If you want to clean that warning. Just do like this:

```
NSMutableString *myMutableStringObj = [[myMutableStringObj stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" & " withString:@"And"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: It Shows me same Warning.

Comment: You completely misunderstand how mutable strings work. Use "replaceOccurencesOfString". You are creating two objects without any need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

See the method signeture from [NSString Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/).

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

this method return NSString object.

So you need to convert result into mutalbe string or catch the result in NSString.

Comment: Or - maybe - what about using a method for _mutable_ strings?

Comment: @gnasher you can follow the documentation of the apple. It is very clear and can be understable with no efforts

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for NSString and NSMutableString. That doesn't only apply to you, but to anyone answering here so far. The answers on this thread have been absolutely depressing.

There are methods that can be used for NSString but also work with NSMutableString which create a new, immutable string based on a previous string. Typically methods starting with "stringBy..." will be creating a new string.

And there are methods, in the NSMutableString interface, which *modify* the contents of an existing NSMutableString. Like "replaceOccurencesOfString".

Read the documentation and pick what is right for you. A method starting with "stringBy" is *not* going to modify your mutable string, it's creating a new immutable one. To *modify* a string, use the methods from the NSMutableString interface. Fortunately the compiler tells you when you use the wrong method.

Answer (score -1):

plz use this code

```
 NSMutableString * str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello Testing"];
    str1 = [[str1  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@"B"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
```

Comment: You completely misunderstand how mutable strings work. Use "replaceOccurencesOfString". You are creating three objects when you only need to create one.

Comment: @gnasher729 can you explain where i am using three objects ?